# Is there any graphical bootloader for x86 PCs?

Tags: boot-loader

As you may know while dual booting on windows you get this nice boot menu:
[image: windows graphical bootloader]

I was curious as to whether there is a way to replace the textual looking Grub bootloader with something that look's more like the windows bootloader?

To change this: 
[image: Grub bootloader screen]

into something more windows looking.

I have tried using BURG but it was broken and hasn't been supported since 2013.

Comment: Bootloader for which platform?

Comment: Why does it matter so much to you? You won't book your system very often, and if you do it, you'll get a graphical screen quickly. I won't bother. BTW, GRUB can be configured to show some "graphical" background

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the rEFInd Boot Manager.

Comment: Note that rEFInd requires UEFI, but enabling UEFI mode instead of legacy BIOS is a good idea anyway, if your system supports it.